# Why "$" autocompletion works for S4 class "SummarizedExperiment" from BioConductor

Tags: r, autocomplete, bioconductor, r-s4

I am having hard time understanding how autocompletion can work for a custom made S4 class in BioConductor called "SummarizedExperiment".

Here is a short demonstration taken from `example(SummarizedExperiment)`:

```
library(SummarizedExperiment)

nrows <- 200; ncols <- 6
counts <- matrix(runif(nrows * ncols, 1, 1e4), nrows)

rowRanges <- GRanges(rep(c("chr1", "chr2"), c(50, 150)),
                     IRanges(floor(runif(200, 1e5, 1e6)), width=100),
                     strand=sample(c("+", "-"), 200, TRUE),
                     feature_id=sprintf("ID%03d", 1:200))

colData <- DataFrame(Treatment=rep(c("ChIP", "Input"), 3), row.names=LETTERS[1:6])

rse <- SummarizedExperiment(assays=SimpleList(counts=counts),
                            rowRanges=rowRanges, colData=colData)
```

Now this object is:

```
> structure(rse)
class: RangedSummarizedExperiment
dim: 200 6
metadata(0):
assays(1): counts
rownames: NULL
rowData names(1): feature_id
colnames(6): A B ... E F
colData names(1): Treatment
```

Seems to have it's own generic `$` function [LINK](https://github.com/Bioconductor/SummarizedExperiment/blob/master/R/SummarizedExperiment-class.R#L575):

```
setMethod("$", "SummarizedExperiment",
    function(x, name)
{
    colData(x)[[name]]
})
```

Yet when I press *tab* in R console it autocompletes the possible names for `$`:

```
rse$<tab>
rse$Treatment
```

Why is this happening? I thought R only autocompleted `$` for lists.

Comment: Not sure what the question is. This is probably not R functionality you're looking at. If my hunch is correct and you are using RStudio, [tag:rstudio] tag is actually appropriate here.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I am not using R-studio. I tried to indicate that in the question by specifying "when I press tab in R console".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation of tab completion is via the S3 generic `?.DollarNames`. For SummarizedExperiment, the [relevant method](https://github.com/Bioconductor/SummarizedExperiment/blob/master/R/SummarizedExperiment-class.R#L572) is

```
.DollarNames.SummarizedExperiment <- function(x, pattern = "")
    grep(pattern, names(colData(x)), value=TRUE)
```

Approximately, when the tab key is pressed, R looks for a pattern `x$foo<tab>`, finds that `x` is a SummarizedExperiment, and so looks for `.DollarNames.SummarizedExperiment` to evaluate, passing `x` as the first argument and `foo` as the second, offering completions returned by the method.

In contrast, when the carriage return is pressed `x$foo<cr>`, R sees that you are trying to invoke `$` on `x`, and so looks for the (S4) method for `$`.

Comment: thanks a lot. This is new to me and very useful. Do you happen to know if it's possible to do something similar for autocompletion after `@` slots as well?

Comment: `@` access to slots in interactive code would not be considered 'good practice'; this is accessing the internal implementation of the class, and a major tenant of object-oriented programming is to separate the implementation from the interface. But yes, tab completion works on  `x@<tab>` and does not require any method on the part of the developer. This is discussed on `?.DollarNames`.

Comment: I am considering writing and S3 class which overloads @ to access some attributes so having custom autocompletion for @ would be useful in this context. But seems like it is reserved for S4 class slots.